# Debug jsrender template

Tags: jquery-templates, jsrender

If I have any syntax error in jsrender its hard to debug. Is there any way to debug.

I use `{{*debugger;}}` and `$.views.settings.allowCode=true;`

and

```
$.views.settings.debugMode(true);
```

But none of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new documentation topic which has been added to www.jsviews.com, here:

[Error handling and debugging](http://www.jsviews.com/#onerror)

which should answer your questions...

Comment: I use the jsrender minified js which doesn't print the error message. I changed it to development version(jsrender.js) now its works fine.

Comment: Setting $.views.settings.debugMode(true) should  work just the same when using the minified jsrender.min.js - and render the error messages as expected.  (My testing confirms it works correctly). Can you verify - and let me know, or post a jsfiddle if it does not work for you?

Comment: I update the v0.9.74 and its working fine now for minified js. Can you please help for this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919883/get-current-index-of-for-tag-in-jsrender. Thanks