# Get current index of for tag in jsrender

Tags: jquery-templates, jsrender

Is there any way to get the current index of `for` tag in the tag.

**Need an solution**

```
{{for ~ID=#index}}
     {{:~ID}}
{{/for}}
```

It will not work because `#index` is accessible only within the for loop.

**Working Code:**

```
{{for}}
     {{:#index}}
{{/for}}
```

And is there any way to access the Jsonobject key and value in `for` tag instead of `prop` tag.

```
{{for arrayOfObj}}
   {{:#data.key}} //In here data is a jsonobject. 
   //I need an key and value of this object.
{{/for}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. You have an array of objects - OK so what do you want to do?

If you want to iterate over the array you can write `{{for arrayOfObj}}...{{/for}}`.

Now, inside that block you can get the index and the object. If you want to get a specific known key (if you know the object has a `name` property for example) you can write `{{:name}}`.

But if you want to iterate over all of the properties of each object, you can use `{{props}}` (for each object, within the `{{for}}` block):

```
{{for arrayOfObj}} - iterate over array
  {{:#index}} - this is the index in the array
  {{:name}}
  {{props}} - iterate over props of this object
    {{:key}}
    {{:prop}}
    {{:#getIndex()}} - this is the index in the array
  {{/props}}
{{/for}}
```

Comment: I try to access the index within the tag. {{for arrayOfObj ~ObjectinIndex=arrayOfObj[#index]}}{{/for}}

In here i need a index of for tag within a tag